# Как сделать изменение размера содержимого WebBrowser в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser

Здравствуйте! 
Имеется **webBrowser** на форме. Не знаю, как сделать **zoom** содержимого. Задача заключается в том, чтобы содержимое было выравнено по ширине **webBrowser'a**. Подскажите,  как это сделать?

Comment: Видимо, исключительно зажав CTRL и прокручивая колесо вперед на уже запущенном приложении...

Comment: во-первых, так не работает, а во-вторых, нужно сделать программно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ОК. Специально для этого вопроса затратил свое время, около 2 часов. Сам занимался веб-браузером по работе. Вот ответ:

В WPF часть возможностей по нашему старенькому IE вынесено на внешнюю ссылку. По-этому мы можем обратиться к нужным методам самого документа в двух вариантах: 1. через **`dynamic`** - нужно при одноразовой команде; 2. через добавленную обертку - когда реально будешь работать с внутренним документом.

1) Создал метод из одного форума, адаприровал его под WPF

```
using System.Reflection;
enum ExecCommands
{
    OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM = 63
}
enum ExecOpts
{
    OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT = 0,
    OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER = 1,
    OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2,
    OLECMDEXECOPT_SHOWHELP = 3
}

void Zoom(WebBrowser webbrowser, int iZoom)
   {
     if (webbrowser == null || webbrowser.Document == null || iZoom <= 0) return;
     object document = webbrowser.Document;
     FieldInfo fi = typeof(WebBrowser).GetField("_axIWebBrowser2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
     object axwebbrowser = fi.GetValue(webbrowser);
     axwebbrowser.GetType().InvokeMember("ExecWB", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, axwebbrowser, new object[] { ExecCommands.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM,
     ExecOpts.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, iZoom, IntPtr.Zero});
}
```

---

Если вам нужно сделать более мощную обертку или посмотреть доп. команды, это вы найдете на одном из ответов на форуме [ЗДЕСЬ](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/webbrowser-zooming-wpf-90973.aspx)

2.1) Есть обертка. Она может помочь в редактировании и использовании самого контента, но для управления браузером не очень подходит. Заходим в References -> COM -> Microsoft HTML Object Library

Далее

```
    mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
    doc.parentWindow.execScript("document.body.style.zoom='" + iZoom + "%';");
```

Недостаток очевиден, но просто.

2.2) В WPF можно вставить `WindowsFormHost`, а в него вставить `WinForm` браузер, который даже лучше нового `WPF`. Референс соответственно нужен `.NET -> System.Windows.Forms`. В нем можно привязаться на прямую к `ActiveXInstance` и дать ей команду, схожую с первым пунктом, но только более красиво:

```
    dynamic axInstance = winformBrowser.ActiveXInstance;
    axInstance.ExecWB(ExecCommands.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM,
     ExecOpts.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, iZoom, null);
```

Выбирайте варианты, которые вам подходят. Ну если что, то на будущее нужно потом переходить на [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/), но только когда он будет более работоспособный и стабильный, чем `IE Control`.

Спасибо за внимание, жду +)